# Issues with mongoRestore [listCollections requires authentication]

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I am trying to restore a MongoDB on an EC2 instance. I am currently running Mongo 4.0. I am restoring a .tgz, which I then unzip, and it contains a directory with all of my files. I previously used this command:

```
sudo mongorestore --db newDB mongoDump-2018-07-25-0200/viboDB/
```

Now that I am trying to update our database, I am getting the following error.

```
building a list of collections to restore from mongoDump-2018-07-25/0200 dir
Failed: viboBI2.Songs: error reading database: command listCollections requires authentication
```

I have logged into the mongo shell, and used db.auth() to authenticate as an admin. I have tried restarting mongo as well. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried passing user and password to `mongorestore` command?

Comment: I thought I tried it, but I misspelled my username! That would explain it. For anyone looking at this thread in the future, this worked: sudo mongorestore --db newDB -u user -p password  mongoDump-2018-07-25-0200/viboDB/

Answer (score 10):

For restoring the Database you need to provide authentication.

```
mongorestore -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD --authenticationDatabase admin -d dbNAME PATH/TO/DIRECTORY
```

you can also provide host and port by adding `-h` and `--port`

Comment: Cool, you can use `--noIndexRestore` to ignore the indexes

Comment: `--authenticationDatabase admin` was so useful. tnx bro.